# .htaccess seen as not writable, but it does is

Tags: wordpress, apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

just installed Apache 2.4 on a Centos 7 virtual machine from scratch. I then installed wordpress, created a virtual host at the directory: /var/www/html/my_site. Unfortunately permalinks were not being updated because .htaccess was not writable (that’s the error message). Really weird, because the file is within the root directory and IT IS WRITABLE, just checked many times, tried any kind of permission code: 664, 640, 755, 777.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of SELinux with command.

```
getenforce
ls -lZ .htaccess
```

For troubleshooting, you can disable SELinux with command

`setenforce 0`